# Set Time Interval for Fetching Data inside React Life Cycle Methods

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I am building up a react application for showing data in rest-api.In order to do that I have used the componentDidMount method and successfully getting the data without any confusions. My code snippet is as in below.

```
  componentDidMount() {
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/sensors')
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(json => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              sensors: json,
            })
            console.log(this.state.sensors);
          });

  }
```

My requirement is to fetch data in every 40 seconds and update the table without refreshing the web page. Can anyone help me for sorting this out?

Comment: Does it have to be a class component? It's easier to write for a function component

Comment: You can use setInterval but make sure you clearInterval when the component unmounts.

Answer (score 0):

According to my requirement as I need to load the table data in 40seconds time intervals I can use Javascript inbuilt method **setInterval()** inside **componentWillMount()** method.
As shown in the question initial data loading just after the **render()** can be done from **componentDidMount()**.

Below is my code for fetching data in 40 second time intervals.

```
 componentWillMount(){
     setInterval(() => {
      fetch('http://localhost:5000/sensors')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          sensors: json,
        })
        console.log(this.state.sensors);
      });
     }, 40000);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge i think it is impossible to update state without re-rendering the component (without mutating state) since react uses shallow rendering, it basically checks previous and current state and rerenders if they do not match, if you ask me, to do it without memory leaks and bunch of bugs, you could

a) use a separate component for the fetching purpose and displaying results (as  you said table) so only that component rerenders (and use redux or contextAPI. whichever you want),
also you can use componentWillUnmount (which will be deprecated) when user renders another page to clear the interval. (or you could use hooks and just return function which cleans interval)

```
 useEffect(()=>{
     const interval = setInterval(()=>{
         //fetch here
     },40000);
     return () => {
         cleanInterval(interval)
     }
 },[tableData /*this is supposed to be the state value of the data you fetch*/])
```

b) mutate state. **WHICH IS NOT A GOOD IDEA** (it would result in more bugs and errors)